# Unable to make code run - Error in `lag()`:! `n`

Tags: r

I need help solving this error, I am not sure how to, but it seems as when I run the "dp_stat" in the end, an error appears when I do my OLS model. Essentially I try to find the cumulative difference between a benchmark and a given individual predictive model. Here dp is my independent variable and sg is my dependent variable. datanu is my excel data. I'm not sure how to attach the data here, however here is a link to the excel and the code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12BOuNBODURIP7CQIBZWMmHFc1d7zXHxN?usp=sharing If anyone has a fix it would mean the world!

"#Error in lag():! n must be a positive integer, not a double vector of length 1."

```
rm(list= ls())  # Clear global environment
invisible(gc()) # Free up unused R-occupied memory
cat("\014")     # Clear console output: equivalent to ctrl + L 

library("tseries")
library("readxl")
library("Metrics")
library("lubridate")
library("ggplot2")
library("data.table")
library("dyn")
library("reshape2")

#header TRUE fordi første row er navne.
datanu <- read_xlsx("~/Documents/6.semester/Bachelor/Data/datanu.xlsx",
                    na = "NaN",
                    sheet = "datax", 
)


myts <- ts(datanu, start=c(1872, 1), end=c(2020, 12), frequency=12)
plot(myts[, c("dp", "dy", "ep", "de")])


get_statistics <- function(myts, dp, sg, h=1, start=1872, end=2020, est_periods_OOS = 20) {
  #### IS ANALYSIS
  
  #1. Historical mean model for en portefølje
  avg   <- mean(window(myts, start, end)[, sg], na.rm=TRUE)
  IS_error_N <- (window(myts, start, end)[, sg] - avg)             
  
  
  #2. OLS model
  #reg <- dyn$lm(sg ~ lag(as.numeric(dp), 1), data=window(myts, start, end)) 
  reg <- dyn$lm(eval(parse(text=sg)) ~ lag(eval(parse(text=dp)), -1), data=window(myts, start, end))    #Error in `lag()`:! `n` must be a positive integer, not a double vector of length 1.
  IS_error_A <- reg$residuals
  
  
  #OOS ANALYSIS
  OOS_error_N <- numeric(end - start - est_periods_OOS)  
  OOS_error_A <- numeric(end - start - est_periods_OOS)  
  
  #anvender kun information op til forecasten er lavet. 
  j <- 0
  for (i in (start + est_periods_OOS):(end-1)) {
    j <- j + 1
    #Get the actual ERP that you want to predict
    actual_ERP <- as.numeric(window(myts, i+1, i+1)[, sg])
    
    #1. Historical mean model
    OOS_error_N[j] <- actual_ERP - mean(window(myts, start, i)[, sg], na.rm=TRUE)
    
    #2. OLS model
    reg_OOS <- dyn$lm(eval(parse(text=sg)) ~ lag(eval(parse(text=dp)), -1), 
                      data=window(myts, start, i))
    #Compute_error
    df <- data.frame(x=as.numeric(window(myts, i, i)[, dp]))
    names(df) <- dp
    pred_ERP   <- predict.lm(reg_OOS, newdata=df)    
    OOS_error_A[j] <-  pred_ERP - actual_ERP
    
  }
  
  #Compute statistics 
  MSE_N <- mean(OOS_error_N^2)
  MSE_A <- mean(OOS_error_A^2)
  T <- length(!is.na(myts[, sg]))
  OOS_R2  <- 1 - MSE_A/MSE_N
  #Is the -1 enough (maybe -2 needed because of lag)?
  OOS_oR2 <- OOS_R2 - (1-OOS_R2)*(reg$df.residual)/(T - 1)       
  dRMSE <- sqrt(MSE_N) - sqrt(MSE_A)
  ##
  
  #### CREATE PLOT
  IS  <- cumsum(IS_error_N[2:length(IS_error_N)]^2)-cumsum(IS_error_A^2)
  OOS <- cumsum(OOS_error_N^2)-cumsum(OOS_error_A^2)
  df  <- data.frame(x=seq.int(from=start + 1 + est_periods_OOS, to=end), 
                    IS=IS[(1 + est_periods_OOS):length(IS)], 
                    OOS=OOS) #Because you lose one observation due to the lag
  #Shift IS errors vertically, so that the IS line begins 
  # at zero on the date of first OOS prediction. (se Goyal/Welch (2008, side 1465))
  df$IS <- df$IS - df$IS[1] 
  df  <- melt(df, id.var="x") 
  plotGG <- ggplot(df) + 
    geom_line(aes(x=x, y=value,color=variable)) + 
    geom_rect(data=data.frame(),#Needed by ggplot2, otherwise not transparent
              aes(xmin=2008, xmax=2010,ymin=-0.2,ymax=0.2), 
              fill='red',
              alpha=0.1) + 
    scale_y_continuous('Cumulative SSE Difference', limits=c(-0.2, 0.2)) + 
    scale_x_continuous('Year')
  ##
  
  return(list(IS_error_N = IS_error_N,
              IS_error_A = reg$residuals,
              OOS_error_N = OOS_error_N,
              OOS_error_A = OOS_error_A,
              IS_R2 = summary(reg)$r.squared, 
              IS_aR2 = summary(reg)$adj.r.squared, 
              OOS_R2  = OOS_R2,
              OOS_oR2 = OOS_oR2,
              dRMSE = dRMSE,
              plotGG = plotGG))
  
}

dp_stat <- get_statistics(myts, "dp", "sg", start=1872)    
dp_stat$plotGG
```

Comment: Take a look again at [ask] and the *minimal* part of [mcve]. You've posted more than 100 lines of code, starting with a line that will clear out any work people might have in their environment, and requiring several not-so-common packages to be installed. Your first step in debugging should be identifying where exactly the error occurs—at a glance and without having to install new packages, I can't tell which of the `lag` calls that might be. That means paring the code down to the essentials, i.e. not making a plot, not doing all the model diagnostics, probably not in a loop or a function

Comment: I mention that it is when I run the OLS, so this line:
```reg <- dyn$lm(eval(parse(text=sg)) ~ lag(eval(parse(text=dp)), -1), data=window(myts, start, end))```

Comment: You run `lm` with a lag twice though. I hadn't seen that you flagged that line until I scrolled far enough to the side to notice the comment. Something like that should be much more obvious in the post, not just for us to help you but for your own debugging

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, `n must be a positive integer, not a double vector of length 1.` The error comes from you providing `n = -1` (i.e., a negative number) as an argument. I assume your idea is to have a negative number of positions to lag by. However, the `lag()` function only accepts a positive number of lag positions. Instead of `lag()`, you should use `lead()` with `n = 1` to achieve the desired result.